# Inequality constrained convex optimization in Matlab

Tags: function, optimization, matlab

I want to solve the following problem:

minimize        E[T]

subject to      λi * pi - μi <=  0;   for all i, i=1,...,n

(λ0 + sum(λi*(1-pi))) - μ0 <=0;

```
            pi-1 <=0;    for all i, i=1,...,n

            pi =>  0;    for all i, i=1,...,n
```

where E(T) = (λ0 + sum(λi*(1-pi)) / ( ( λ0 + sum(λi) ) * μ0 -(λ0 + sum(λi*(1-pi) ) )) + sum((pi * λi) / ((λ0 + sum(λi)) * (μi - pi * λi)) )

where all sum goes from 1 to n

That's what we know about the parameters: n = 2, λ0 = 0,  μ0 = 1,  λ1 = free parameter, λ2 = 2, μ1 = μ2 = 2,

This problem can be handled as an inequality constrained minimization
problem.

I know that  λ1 goes from 0 to 3 and what i want to get are p1 and p2. p1 and p2 are between 0 and 1.

And how can i choose the starting points?  Or is this problem can be solved in Matlab?

I tried to to use fmincon with interior point algorithm in Matlab. But i don't really know how a linearly increasing parameter can be in nonlinear constraints.

If you can tell me suggestions or other functions that can handle this problem properly i would be pleased.